# javascript add option item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to move an Option from one List to a second List, at the same time each item added to the second list should also be added to a drop down list.

I have the following javascript

```
    $("#MoveRight,#MoveLeft").click(function (event) {
        var id = $(event.target).attr("id");
        var selectFrom = id == "MoveRight" ? "#Items" : "#SelectedCustomFields";
        var moveTo = id == "MoveRight" ? "#SelectedCustomFields" : "#Items";
        var selectedItems = $(selectFrom + " :selected").toArray();


        $.each(selectedItems, function (val, text) {
            createOption(val, text, $('#SortBy'));
            createOption(val, text, $(moveTo));
        });

        selectedItems.remove();
    });


    function createOption(value, text, list) {
        var myList = list;

            myList
                .append($("<option></option>")
                    .val(value).html(text));

    }
```

The issue with this seems to be that it adds to one of the Select Lists fine. In the above case the second createOption call works fine, the 1st one adds a blank item, if i swap those function calls around it also flips the results. I have also tried changing the createOption function to hard code it to add the same values to the second select list (the drop down) but this gets the same results.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing `.toArray();`? That is weird when you could just use .each of the jQuery set.

Comment: @epascarello `$(event.target).attr("id")` instead of `this.id` is also not-very-good-code. The more you know about jQuery and JS, the better code is.

Comment: @AndrewHanson can you provide related HTML?

Comment: I'm using toarray because originally I was just doing one single append to the list box as I didn't have the drop down at that point

Comment: In response to providing HTML. I'm not sure how much help that will be as it's razor listboxfor and dropdownlistfor

Comment: @AndrewHanson well, then all that I can suggest is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eu0ea71/)